# Datagram IP Changed when reached container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I am trying to establish UDP communication, my server is running on host machine and client running in a container. I send an initial broadcast with server IP.

But, Docker changes the Ip address of my datagram packet to its gateway address from host IP and therefore my java application running inside the container cannot send UDP packets to host.

Is there a way to preserve the Host's IP in the datagram?

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  cs:
    image: connectivity:latest
    hostname: cs
    restart: always
    ports:
      # external:internal
      - "8088:9980"
      - "24005:24005/udp"
    volumes:
      - ../../../target:/home
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq-server
    network_mode: host
    networks:
      hnet:
        aliases:
         - cs
    cap_add:
      - ALL
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9980"
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbitmq-server"
      DCX_CS_RABBITMQ_PORT: "5672"
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "local,integration"

  rabbitmq-server:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq-server
    restart: always
    networks:
    network_mode: host
      hnet:
        aliases:
         - rabbitmq-server
    ports:
      # external:internal
      - "5680:5672"
      - "15680:15672"
      - "32780:32768"
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to run your container with network mode `host`:

```sh
docker run --network=host <docker_image>
```

In [host mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), your container will use the docker host network interface instead of having its own, and as such will share the same IP address as the docker host. Be aware that in this mode, any port opened by your container is opened on the docker host network interface, and this even without *publishing* ports.

Comment: Thank you, my container depends on another container. should it be run in host mode? when I tried, I saw an unknown host exception in my logs,  rabbitmq-server hostname could not be resolved. I added  my docker-compose to the question. I am running Docker natively on mac.

Comment: you would, but then connect to rabbit on `localhost:5672`

Comment: when I use --net=host, & localhost:15672 doesn't work. I think this is a Mac limitation and it won't let me publish ports:), obviously.

Answer (score 0):

used host.docker.internal as a workaround for server IP to reach the server from the container.